# Have AngularJS inject dependencies into objects like it already does for controllers

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angularjs

I'm using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) 1.0.2 with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) 1.8.2 and I'm trying to have AngularJS inject dependencies into objects, like it does for controllers. You can find a basic example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kappa/3fbZx/), in there you'll find two controllers (`List` and `NewItem`), an object (`Item`) and a module with a service (named `services` and `communication` respectively).

My problem is with `Item`:

```js
var Item = function (name, price) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = name;
    self.price = price;

    self.pretty = function () {
        return self.name + ": " + self.price;
    };
};
```

In it I need to use some things outside, let's say I want the `pretty` method to format the `price` property to a currency-aware string:

```js
self.pretty = function () {
    return self.name + ": " + $filter("currency")(self.price);
};
```

But this won't work, as `$filter` is not defined. (Mind you, the usage of `$filter` is only an example, it could be anything.)

And modifying `var Item = function (name, price) {` to `var Item = function ($filter, name, price) {` won't work too, as it's not AngularJS who's creating the object (as in the case of the controllers), it's me.

So, how can I have AngularJS create the object for me, or have it resolve the dependency I need?

Something like `var item = angular.create(Item, $scope.name, $scope.price);` or `var item = new Item(angular.inject("filter"), $scope.name, $scope.price);` I think...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible to ask AngularJS to instantiate your own objects (and inject dependencies into them!) by using the [$injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector) service and its [instantiate(Type, locals)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector#instantiate) method.

For example, given a constructor like this:

```
var Item = function ($filter, name, price) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = name;
    self.price = price;

    self.pretty = function () {
        return $filter('json')(self);
    };
};
```

one could create an instance of `Item` like so:

```
var item = $injector.instantiate(Item, { name: $scope.name, price: $scope.price });
```

Please note that the `instantiate` method accepts 2 arguments:

- Type: a constructor function.
- locals: a hash of values that should **not** be injected but rather taken as-is.

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7pgt/) (a simplified version of the initial one).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I *had* looked at `$injector` doc page, but missed `instantiate(type, locals)`... Sigh...